# Reduction Type of Primes is $\mathbb Q$-Isogeny Invariant for Elliptic Curves over $\mathbb Q$

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves

I thought it was the case that if two elliptic curves $E/\mathbb Q$ and $E'/\mathbb Q$ are $\mathbb Q$-isogenous, then they have the same primes of each reduction type. My rationale was that they have the same $L$-function, hence the same $a_p$ (coefficients) for each prime $p$, and the $a_p$ are determined by *exactly* which reduction type $E$ (resp. $E'$) has at $p$.

However, I cannot seem to square this fact with some of the other general theory. For example, it is easy to see using calculus that no short Weierstrass model of an elliptic curve over $\mathbb Q$ has good reduction at 2; this can also be seen via the discriminant. But, for example, $y^2 + y = x^3$ is an elliptic curve over $\mathbb Q$ which is $\mathbb Q$-isomorphic to $y^2 = x^3 + 32$. However, the former has good reduction at 2, while the latter does not. Evidently I have a fundamental misunderstanding of what is going on here.

Comment: The whole notion of good reduction for an elliptic curve is “it has a good model”. The good model doesn’t have to be the one you’re given.

Comment: So is it even true that $\mathbb Q$-isogenous elliptic curves have the same, say, primes of multiplicative reduction?

Comment: I’d tentatively say “yes” because these should be completely encoded in the Galois representation (or the $L$-function), but you should check reliable sources (eg Silverman).

Comment: Silverman only says that Q-isogenous elliptic curves over Q share the same primes of good and bad reduction. The definition of the local L-factors and the agreement of the L-functions seems to indicate that what I have said is true, but I spoke with an expert number theorist recently who told me this was false (but could not give me details).

Comment: If $f:E\to E'$ is an isogeny defined over $\Bbb{Q}$ then $\Bbb{Q}(E')$ is the subfield of $\Bbb{Q}(E)$ fixed by $A\to A+B$ for each $B\in \ker f$.

If $E$ has good reduction at $p\nmid |\ker f|$ then $\Bbb{F}_p(E \bmod p)$ has a subfield fixed by each $Q\to Q+P, P\in (\ker f) \bmod p$ and this field is $\Bbb{F}_p(E'\bmod p)$ the good reduction of $E'$.

Comment: If we accept the LMFDB exposition, the “broad” reduction type (good, split/non split multiplicative, additive) is, indeed, predicted by the $L$-function. We can see on the tables that more subtle invariants (valuation of a minimal discriminant, of $j$, Tamagawa numbers, Kodaira symbols) aren’t preserved, on the other hand.